# FileNotFound Exception but the file exists

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I tried to read a file using the `java.io.File` class but it was throwing `filenotfound exception`. But the file is there and when I use the `exists` method it returns `false`

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    File file = new File("q.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
}
```

Comment: Is there where? In the directory you're executing the program from?

Comment: where is this file located? did you try to write the full adress?

Comment: You need to declare the file path as well

Comment: seems to be a relative path problem...please try to give a full path and access it

Comment: Change `File file = new File("q.txt");` to `File file = new File("q.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());` to show where the JVM actually thinks that file is (& start debugging this)..

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the complete path in the File constructor

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    File file = new File("Please provide complete path here");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file is under the project folder and not in the package folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to provide the relative path to the file by providing the filename.

Please provide the absolute path of the file . For e.g.

```
File f = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
```